# How to setText in selected textView

Tags: java, android

Needed some help here. In my map test app I have 2 Autocomplete textViews. First textView gets the address of marker on load as well as chages the address if map is dragged.

But I am struggling for second textView where I need the same feature depending which textView is active.

I tried it like:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView mFromAddress;
private AutoCompleteTextView mToAddress;

mFromAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
mToAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.toAddress);

// Decoder Coding.. str prints address
if (mFromAddress.isSelected()) {
    mFromAddress.setText(str);
} else if (mToAddress.isSelected()) {
    mToAddress.setText(str);
}
```

But no expected results. Even the first textView stops working.

I am new to java and Android Studio. I am looking for some suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hasFocus()` function

```
if (mFromAddress.hasFocus()) {
    mFromAddress.setText(str);
} else if (mToAddress.hasFocus()) {
    mToAddress.setText(str);
}
```

Another way is that define another TextView in code and set it as active `TextView` when focus change in `OnFocusChangeListener`

```
AutoCompleteTextView activeET;
activeET = mFromAddress;  // set mFromAddress as active text in start

mFromAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
            activeET = mFromAddress;
    }
});

mToAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus)
            activeET = mToAddress;
    }
});
```

Now you just need to set text to `activeET`

```
activeET.setText(str);
```

Comment: I am sorry, didn't work either. It did the same thing what `isSelected` did. Do I have to add some additional line of code in order to use `isSelected` or `hasFocus`? Or using `onClickListener` sessions would be a good idea to hold these values?

Comment: Thank you so much @SiSa.. Code works fine.. I have a little trouble here.. I have another method applied which removes the focus if clicked anywhere else on the map other that AutocompleteTextView.. And I think thats what causing the problem.. Can't figure out work around with that.

Comment: @Sebastian If the focus change from your AutocompleteTextView to another view, activeET still indicate last focused AutocompleteTextView. so is there any other problem?